# How do I ensure my CloudKit container will be functional when submitting my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cloudkit

I have a fully completed app, it uses CloudKit in basic ways, saving and loading mostly text files. In development mode it works perfect, but when posting the app to the AppStore and using the final product it has 0 CloudKit functionality. I'm certain this problem is because of a technicality in my entitlements, or provisining profiles. If someone has experience with this I would really appreciate knowing what the most common or most probable reason for this is? Thanks

Comment: Have you migrated your development environment to the production environment? 

You have to do this to make the schema you created available to the public.

You can test your app in the production environment by setting the "com.apple.developer.icloud-services" key for "com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment" to "Production" in your app entitlements.

Comment: Thank you that worked!! I also had all my code signings set to development instead of distribution, don't know if that made a difference. And I didn't realize I had to also adjust permissions for different types of my cloud users. Any other rookies reading this, do these 3 things: customize security settings in your cloud dashboard if you want any users to be able to create/read records. Set code signing and entitlements to distribution. And deploy your development cloud to production from the dashboard. This site is very helpful!